# Accessing an uploaded file on frontend with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, url, upload, laravel-storage

I upload and store picture. Into my **blade.php** I have this line:

```
<img src="{{ storage_path('app\\'. $image) }}" />
```

this line generate this line:

```
<img src="C:\laragon\www\ProjectName\storage\app\uploads/images/IQeJo4w9lKqSxufTySpYKv1m9Z0TOV3PIYIvlN3g.jpeg" />
```

The image doesn't appears, but if I **copy/past** the `C:\` link into my browser urlfield, I have the image visible.

Have you any idea to show the image with the img tag?

Answer (score 2):

If you have created symlink you can access the file with

```
$path = asset('storage/' . $image);
```

try and let me know.

Comment: This is what I do and it works. It this doesn't work, try removing the symlink  and recreating it using ```php artisan storage:link``` again.

Answer (score 2):

You stored your image inside `/storage/app/uploads`, which is *not* a public directory. The public directory is `/storage/app/public`.

To save an image to the public disk instead, try this in a file upload controller:

```php
$path = $request->file('image')->storePublicly('uploads/images');
```

(Save `$path` to the database)

Then inside your blade view:

```php
<img src="{{ Storage::disk('public')->url($path) }}">
```

For this to work, you also need to link the public storage disk if you have not already:

```php
php artisan storage:link
```

---

`storage_path()` gives you the *internal* path to the file, which will not work for creating links to an image that can be served by a webserver.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your anwser. your method give me the link "<img src="/storage/uploads/images/vGP3xDAp0xBntK5aD2Oj2OnKBvp1t6tQa1l6rZyT.jpeg" />" but I have a 404 error

Comment: With "storage/app/uploads/..." i have the 404 error too :)

Comment: @YannBtd that link is correct. Have you run `php artisan storage:link` so that your webserver will be able to find it?

Comment: @YannBtd I've also updated the answer to use `Storage::disk('public')` to make the url, which will prefix the link with your `APP_URL` environment setting in case your website is located under a subfolder (i.e. your url looks like `http://localhost/mysite/public`)

Answer (score 1):

`storage_path` will give you the absolute path to the file on your local file system. You should never use this as a public URL. It won't work either. The reason you can see this image is because the web server is probably running on your own system.

Files in the `storage` folder are outside of the hosted part of the website and because of this not directly accessible.

You should take a look at [the public disk](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/filesystem#the-public-disk) if you want your files to be accessible directly.

Comment: yes, i tried to: <img src="{{ asset('storage/app/'.$image) }}" /> <img src="http://localhost:8000/storage/app/uploads/images/IQeJo4w9lKqSxufTySpYKv1m9Z0TOV3PIYIvlN3g.jpeg" />

and i already maked the command: The "public/storage" directory already exists. When i (re)upload the picture, the symlink directory are empty and all link like the follows return 404:

Comment: {{ asset('public/storage/'.$image) }}, {{ asset('storage/app/'.$image) }}, {{ asset($image) }}, etc...

Answer (score 0):

@Travis: I have this:

```
'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),

'asset_url' => env('ASSET_URL', null),
```