# Laravel can not found a stored file 404 not NOT FOUND

Tags: php, laravel, file, laravel-8

I'm a just a beginner and I need your help.
*EDIT : even when I search http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/uploaded/the_filename* I get 404 no found

I've already used php artisan storage:link
I get error `404 Not Found` when I use `<iframe src="/storage/uploaded/{{$data->doc}}">`.

Even if I write `<iframe src="/storage/uploaded/1628544440.docx">` I still get `404 Not Found`. `1628544440.docx` is the file name in DB and `uploaded` folder.

The documents in the folder `/storage/app/public/uploaded` have the same name of `documents->doc` in the Database.

What can I change in the code?

In `DocumentController`:

```php
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'doc' =>  'required',...
    ]);

    $document = new document();

    $file = $request->file('doc');
    $filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;
    $file->storeAs('uploaded', $filename);

    $document->doc = $request->input('doc', $filename);
    $document->candidate_id = $candidate_id; 
    $document->save();
}

public function show($id)
{
    // to select a document that belongs to a candidate
    $doc_id = DB::table('documents')
        ->select('id')
        ->where('candidate_id', $id)
        ->first()
        ->id;
    $data =  document::find($doc_id);

    return view('candidate.document', compact('data'));
}
```

In `candidate/document.blade.php`:

```html
<iframe src="/storage/uploaded/{{ $data->doc }}"></iframe>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is storage in the root directory? You might want to try `./storage` for the current directory.

Comment: Show us your file / folder tree. The path to the file is wrong.

Comment: @infinitezero not it's not in the root directory

Comment: `/` refers to root `./` refers to current and `../` revers to the parent directory.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing an uploaded file on frontend with Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55124827/accessing-uploaded-file-on-frontend-with-laravel)

Comment: @MartinZeitler no I've already check it before posting my  question

Comment: @Sarah The code provided definitely does not represent that. Just use PHPStorm or NetBeans with xdebug... this also supports eg. debugging Blade templates. The documentation explains it in detail: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk (as Ken explained below).

Answer (score 0):

After running the `php artisan storage:link`, check the `<project>/public` folder, there should have the corresponding soft-link folder linked to your storage app folder.

Example

```
ls -la <project>/public
...
lrwxrwxrwx  1 admin   61 Aug  6 12:10 storage -> /home/xxx/storage/app/public/
```

Answer (score 0):

To Save the file:

```
$file = $request->file('doc');
$filename = time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension() ;
$document->doc = $filename;
Storage::disk('local')->put($file, $filename);
```

To access the file

```
{{asset('storage/'.$data->doc)}}
```

Comment: I got this error 'Impossible to create the root directory'